# How do I upload 3d models from firebase storage into react-three-fiber using gltf-loader?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-three-fiber

I want to make an upload system that you can upload INTO firebase storage and then it re-load it back into a gltf-loader in r3f.

I've already setup a gltf loader locally:

```
const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, 'REPLACE THIS WITH FIREBASE URL')
return <primitive object={gltf.scene} />
```

I just don't know how to use firebase or where to find information on it.